Can't apply custom settings when generating client via `nswag openapi2csclient` command
I have the following powershell script where I use nswag openapi2csclient to generate a client. And I'm trying disable settings useBaseUrl and generateBaseUrlProperty
$namespace = "MyNamespace"
$className = "ProductServiceClient"
nswag openapi2csclient /input:swagger.json /classname:$className /namespace:$namespace /output:$className.cs /useBaseUrl:false /generateBaseUrlProperty:false

But when I look at the client that gets generated, it looks like the settings did not get applied.
Also, I did them same thing in Nswag Studio and it works correctly there. Here's a comparison between the two:

Why are the settings not getting applied. Is there something I'm doing wrong?
